# how to call query in default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I want to fetch a query in view/default.ctp( $this->User->find("count");) . That query is common for all pages. Now i am calling that query in all pages . Is it there any alternate way to call query in single time and fetch data into default.ctp. I am using cakephp 2x.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your `AppController::beforeRender()`.

**beforeRender** will be called every time before something is rendered. I don't know why everyone else suggests before*Filter*... It's pretty clear.

[See the documentation.](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_beforeRender)

```
public function beforeRender(){
    parent::beforeRender();
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->set('userCounter',$this->User->find("count"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `appController` there will be `beforeFilter()` function if not, create it and write the following inside it.

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$userCount = $this->User->find("count");
$this->set('userCount',$userCount );
```

now you will be able to access `$userCount` variable in `default.ctp` or any other view

Answer (score 0):

You can call that query e.g in `AppController::beforeFilter` method. Then you can assign result to some variable `$this->set('userCounter',$this->User->find("count"))`
That variable `$userCounter` could be available in any view

```
<?php 
    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->set('userCounter',$this->User->find("count"));
   }
?>
```